# How to handle pasted text correctly via GetConsoleInput()?

Tags: c++, windows, api, console, keyboard

In Windows console, we can use `GetConsoleInput()` to get raw keyboard (and more) input. I want to use it to implement a custom function that read keystrokes with possible CTRL, SHIFT, ALT status. A simplified version of the function is

```
// for demo only, no error checking ...
struct ret {
    wchar_t ch; // 2-byte UTF-16 in Windows
    DWORD control_keys;
};

ret getch() {
    HANDLE in = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    INPUT_RECORD buf;
    DWORD cnt;
    for (;;) {
        ReadConsoleInput(in, &buf, 1, &cnt);
        if (buf.EventType != KEY_EVENT)
            continue;
        const KEY_EVENT_RECORD& rec = buf.Event.KeyEvent;
        if (!rec.bKeyDown)
            continue;
        if (!rec.uChar.UnicodeChar)
            continue;
        return { rec.uChar.UnicodeChar,rec.dwControlKeyState };
    }
}
```

It works fine, except that when I try to paste character not representable in 2 bytes in UTF-16, the `UnicodeChar` field is 0 when `bKeyDown==true`, and the `UnicodeChar` field is the pasted content when  `bKeyDown==false`. Can anyone tell why it is the case and suggest possible workarounds?

Here is some [demo code](https://pastebin.com/1GijwCRY) and [result](https://pastebin.com/DGmMbkB9).

Comment: That's not necessarily just for UTF-16 surrogate pairs. If a character isn't mapped in the keyboard layout, the console's paste routine simulates entering the character as typing an Alt+Numpad sequence, with decimal codes in the OEM codepage. Notice the records in which `wVirtualKeyCode` is `VK_MENU` (Alt). The actual Unicode character is returned in the final Alt key-up record of the sequence. A UTF-16 surrogate pair requires two such sequences.

Comment: BTW, don't use `SetConsoleCP(65001)`, i.e. `SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8)`. It doesn't matter in this case since you're calling wide-character `ReadConsoleInputW`, but the console's multibyte string API (e.g. `ReadFile`, `ReadConsoleA`) does not support UTF-8 as the input codepage. It just replaces non-ASCII characters (i.e. ordinals above 127) with nulls. Unfortunately `SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8)` returns success, which is an outright lie since UTF-8 has never been supported as the console input codepage. Maybe one day they'll fix this, but they've had 24 years to fix it...

Comment: @ErykSun What does it mean "not mapped in the keyboard layout"? Sorry I am not familiar with that. Surely "你好" is not physically on my keyboard, I use MS Pinyin to input both it and "". Why can I use input method to input that ? Besides, when I use alt code, I can see the keystrokes by numpad keys. Why are they not here? Thanks.

Comment: The behavior in a locale that uses IME is different with regards to what's considered input 'typed' by the user. As to why you don't see all of the key-down and key-up input records for typing an Alt+Numpad sequence, I don't know. Could be IME again. If you're running in Windows Terminal (wt.exe) with a ConPTY session that's hosted by openconsole.exe, the behavior is sometimes different from a normal console session hosted by conhost.exe. In a Western locale with a normal console session, I observe the full Alt+Numpad sequence with all key-down and key-up events exactly as if it were typed.

Comment: In particular, pasting the "" emoticon results in 12 input records, 8 of which are key-down and key-up events for entering numpad "6" and "3", i.e. the ordinal 63 for "?" since the surrogate value has no mapping in any OEM codepage. On the key-up record for `VK_MENU` (alt), the `UnicodeChar` has the surrogate code (e.g. 0xd83d). So the actual UTF-16 surrogate pair is sent in the 6th record (lead surrogate) and 12th record (trailing surrogate).

Comment: @ErykSun Looks like you have a great background knowledge regarding this topic! I just discovered that the standard mode of the STD_INPUT_HANDLE (with is with enabled `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT` and `ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT`) will fail to output Unicode which is assembled with an UTF-16 surrogate pair in its echo. This can be easily reproduced using either Command Prompt or PowerShell inside the "Windows Terminal" and then paste e.g.    to the program when it waits in `ReadConsoleW`. If I remove at least ENABLE_LINE_INPUT, it works but I loose all handy input features. Do you know anything about it?